Enable less tech-savvy businesses for transactional SMS using default originator numbers
Our potential tenants (subscribers) to our solution want to be able to send transactional messages such as order-milestone updates to their customers or recipients. All the messages being sent from our solution are templated and are not allowed to be edited. As a solution provider, can i send the text messages on behalf of my tenants, without my tenants having to register their own originator numbers?
I tried reaching out to twilio, I want to know how can the above use-case be enabled without violating the compliance around it.

This post about Twilio ISVs might be helpful for you.

Twilio is not a multi-tenant environment for users, therefore, it allows the environment to be associated with only one corporate account.
In these cases, Twilio recommends using an account for each partner, or registering as a resale point through the partnership channel.
